# Single-entry Schengen visa question

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a single-entry Schengen visa issued by the Czech Republic. I'm travelling first to Munich. I am staying more days in the Czech Republic than in any other country. The last city I will stay in is Budapest.

Will there be any problem?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it clearer, but in doing so I have made an assumption about the meaning of "I'm staying maximum days in czech republic."  If that assumption was incorrect, please advise.  In particular, if you are spending the entire "duration of stay" allowed by the visa in the Czech Republic, and additional days in other countries, then you will have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no problem, as long as you have enough days on your visa for the entire duration of your stay in the Schengen zone.

Comment: And as long as the whole travel path lies inside the Zone. :-)